# Force a std::vector to free its memory?

Tags: c++, vector

I know that std::vectors do not 'free'  the memory when you call vector.clear(), but how can I do this? I want it to release all of its resources once I clear it but I don't want to destroy it.

Here is what is happening right now.
I have a class called OGLSHAPE and I push these into a vector of them. I was hoping that once I did shapevec.clear() I'd get all my memory back, but only got 3/4 of it back. I'm not 100% sure if this is a memory leak or not so I want to free all the resources to be sure its not a leak. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the swap trick:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void FreeAll( T & t ) {
    T tmp;
    t.swap( tmp );
}

int main() {
    std::vector <int> v;
    v.push_back( 1 );
    FreeAll( v );
}
```

Comment: Neil, is there a reason you're having `tmp` or is that just a question of style and personal preferences?

Comment: @sbi Both :-) And I think it's clearer.

Comment: @Neil: Yeah, my wording was bad, I meant to ask whether there's a _technical_ reason. Anyway, thanks for answering. I might have been poisoned by the _C Terseness Virus_, but I actually do prefer `std::vector<T>().swap(v)`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the swap trick:

```
std::vector<Shape>().swap(shapes);
```